# Why am I getting strange ActionView::MissingTemplate errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting a lot of errors like these lately:

```
An ActionView::MissingTemplate occurred in pages#home:

 Missing template pages/home, application/home with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:xml, "application/xml;"], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby]}. Searched in:
 * "/home/MyApp/app/views"



-------------------------------
Request:
-------------------------------

 * URL        : http://www.myapp.com/
 * HTTP Method: GET
 * IP address : 50.125.101.219
 * Parameters : {"controller"=>"pages", "action"=>"home"}
 * Timestamp  : 2017-11-25 00:06:28 +0100
 * Server : MyApp
 * Rails root : /home/MyApp
 * Process: 19546
```

Are these caused by bots crawling my site?

I haven't been able to reproduce these errors through tampering with the URL. Can anybody tell me how to stop them?

Comment: `:formats=>[:xml, "application/xml;"]` - yeah its pretty likely it was a bot.

Comment: @max: How can I prevent to get an error when that happens?

Comment: You can use `responds_to { format.html }` or use a class level `responds_to :html`. This will change the error to a `ActionController::UnknownFormat` which is better since it does not return a 500 Internal server error. I don't remember exactly what status code is returned but its one the 4xx codes.